# Remove point in numbers of 4 or more digits?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL 9 and I have a table with a column type `numeric`.
The data in the database is saved like this:

```
id | limit 
23 | 1.485
24 | 35.601
```

I need to replace the `limit` values in the table with integer values, in this example:

- 1.485 → 1485
- 35.601 → 35601

How can I do that?

Comment: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible (e.g. to Postgres 11 or 12)

Comment: I think we need little mo explanation. What should to do with numbers less then 4 digits (for example 1.99)? Is number 1.99 should stay not changed but 1.001 will be increased to 1001? It looks strange for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following update statement while awaiting other answers,

```
update your_table_name
set limit = cast(replace(cast(limit as text),'.','') as numeric)
```

Comment: This wlll update **all** numbers, not just those with 4 or more digits

Comment: @Nick would you mind elaborate? Appreciate a sample test case

Answer (score 1):

You can update the values as @Vivek describes, but you need to qualify the update so that only those numbers with 4 or more digits are updated, which you can check with `SIMILAR TO`:

```
UPDATE data
SET "limit" = CAST(REPLACE(CAST("limit" AS text), '.', '') AS numeric)
WHERE REPLACE(CAST("limit" AS text), '.', '') SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{4,}'
```

For this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE data
    (id int, "limit" numeric)
;

INSERT INTO data
    (id, "limit")
VALUES
    (23, 1.485),
    (24, 35.601),
    (25, 3.2),
    (26, 1.23),
    (27, 23.1)
```

The output is

```
id  limit
23  1485
24  35601
25  3.2
26  1.23
27  23.1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/25f31/1)

Comment: It looks wrong. It looks as we increase limits for random records based on its accuracy? For example 1.001 will be increased to 1001 but 1.01 will not be changed?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I agree - it seems like an odd thing to do. But it is what OP asked for...

Answer (score 1):

If the data type is indeed `numeric`, then there are no points stored in it. These grouping separators must be an artifact of your client software when it converts the numbers to strings.

You can use `to_char` to convert the numbers to strings yourself and foil the misguided machinations of your client software:

```
SELECT to_char(numcol, '99999999') FROM atable;
```

Comment: Your query seems incorrect. It round the numbers instead increase them. `SELECT to_char(35.601, '99999999') FROM atable; -- > return 36`

Comment: Right. I believe that the number is really 1485, and the client only adds "grouping" characters. But maybe the dot is really a decimal separator, then my answer is wrong. So far, OP has not given feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks as result of insert formatted strings into numeric field. 
For example formatted number '1.234' (One thousand two hundred thirty four) inserted as 1.234 (one whole and two hundred thirty four thousandths)

If my suggestion right the problem can be fixed by multiply by 1000, except whole numbers (they a stored right).

So the solution is next:

```
UPDATE table set limit = round(limit * 1000) where limit != round(limit);
```